# sizes after jre update are different

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

After I updated the jre to version 1.8.0_212 the sizes of all my java frames and panels changed to a bigger format. My question now is, if it´s possible to make this undone without changeing the jre or do I have to change all my sizes manually in my projects?

The window should be small, like before. Instead it looks like in [fullscreen mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjC9R.png), the JButtons are too big and the quality is too low now.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A wild guess: This might be related to some Windows-4k-Screen-scaling stuff. Maybe you applied something like https://superuser.com/questions/988379/how-do-i-run-java-apps-upscaled-on-a-high-dpi-display/1207925#1207925 to your `java.exe` or `javaw.exe`, and this setting is no longer necessary with the latest JRE? (Again, a wild guess, but the linked question and the other answers there should be worth a look...)